# Socket Programming in AVD

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-virtual-device

[In this site](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) use socket for send message to the server.
I haven't any Error in this project but I doesn't work and don't show nothings in avd, help me to run it. I think the port number or IP number is false and don't know what number is correct.
Did I need to install something?

Answer (score 1):

try this in client.java

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() { 
    try {
        socket = new Socket();
        InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT);
        socket.connect(socketAddress);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}     
}
```